# Styled-components with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I wanted to use styled-components with TypeScript, but after installing dependencies (types for styled-components, etc.) and after changing the extension of one simple component to .ts, it's informing me that my 'styled.div' component is declared but never read and I have error like this showing on line 8 -

> 'LoginStyled' refers to value but is being used as a type
> here.ts(2749)

With .js extension, everything works fine.
Here is how component looks like:

```
  import React from "react";
import { Card, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";
import styled from "styled-components";
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";

function Login({toggleAlert}) {
  return (
    <LoginStyled>
      <Card body inverse className="login-window">
        <CardTitle>
          <h2>Log in</h2>
        </CardTitle>
        <LoginForm toggleAlert={toggleAlert} />
      </Card>
    </LoginStyled>
  );
}

export default Login;

const LoginStyled = styled.div`
  .login-window {
    background-color: #333;
    border-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  }
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
`;
```

Comment: does it work if you change the file extension to `.tsx` ?

Comment: Yeah, that worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Login` function renders JSX you should change your extension to `.tsx`. `.ts` files don't support added JSX. You can definitely use `styled-component` elements in a `.ts` file if it doesn't include JSX.