# Typescript and styled-components gives error on import

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Take a create-react-app application that was created with typescript:

```
npx create-react-app myapp --template typescript
cd myapp
npm install styled-components@5.0.1
```

Then add styled-components to a typescript file MyButton.tsx.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';  // <<<<< THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR

const MyButtonStyle = styled.button`
  background: #9590eb;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
`;

/**
 * MyButton is a wrapper around a Button component.  Props/arguments are:
 * onClick(event:object) => void
 * style: Pass style onto <button> element
 */
function MyButton(props:any) {
    return (
        <MyButtonStyle style={props.style} type="button" onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</MyButtonStyle>
    );
}

export default MyButton;
```

And I get the error

```
TypeScript error in .../MyButton.tsx(2,20): Could not find a declaration file for module 'styled-components'. '.../myapp/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

To fix this I renamed the file to *.jsx and the problem went away.
I'm just learning typescript so my thought was I needed to install a typescript library to support `styled-components` but I haven't figured out how to do that (yet).

#### Searching

When searching for a solution I came across the following but they didn't answer the question.

- [Styled-components with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926476/styled-components-with-typescript) - This was a file naming problem (*.ts to *.tsx).
- [Using styled components with Typescript, prop does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404958/using-styled-components-with-typescript-prop-does-not-exist)
- [Using styled-components with props and TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077210/using-styled-components-with-props-and-typescript/52045733#52045733)

Comment: Have you installed the types with `npm install @types/styled-components -D`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a declaration file for module 'styled-components/native'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72690457/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-styled-components-native)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Styled Components library does not ship with types. Instead, you'll need to install it from the Definitely Typed repository.

```
npm i --save-dev @types/styled-components
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Yarn:

```
yarn add @types/styled-components -D
```

Answer (score 1):

for react native

```
yarn add -D @types/styled-components-react-native
```