# Could not find a declaration file for module 'styled-components/native'

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

If you add `styled-components` to your React Native project, there's a sub-directory for the native components specifically:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native`;

export const Container = styled.View`
  ...
`;
```

If you try to do this in a React Native TypeScript project, you'll run into the following typings error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'styled-components/native'.
```

The typical approach to resolving this would be to install the `@types/styled-components` module in your dev dependencies, however this does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2099#issuecomment-749776524

The `styled-components/native` types moved to `@types/styled-components-react-native`.

So, to resolve:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/styled-components-react-native
```

or

```
yarn add -D @types/styled-components-react-native
```

Answer (score 47):

If anybody has `@types/styled-components-react-native` installed and still gets the error maybe it helps the trick as described at https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2370. For me it helped to add the types to `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "some/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "cypress",
      "@testing-library/cypress",
      "@types/styled-components-react-native"
    ]
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The only solution that worked here! If even adding this lines to ```tsconfig.json``` not solve, just reload vscode window if using.

Comment: When I do this, I get errors on all my styled-components that accept children. `Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes`

Answer (score 3):

install

```
npm install --save @types/styled-components
```

Comment: You probably don't want to add the `--save` flag, since it will save it to your `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`. The difference being that `devDependencies` are not used in production. Since TypeScript is not used at runtime you won't any `@types` in production.

Answer (score 2):

**I was facing the same error:**

[image]

To remove this error you can install **@types/styled-components** using the below command.

```
npm install --save @types/styled-components
```

[image]

If still your error persists, then you can below the VS code using below steps:

**Run** Ctrl+Shift+P -or- ⌘+shift+P

**Then type:** Developer: Reload Window and **press enter**.
Your error would be auto-resolved.

[image]